# how can data display thro switch case?

Tags: android

### act=1

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
      lisdis.setAdapter(adapter); 
      lisdis.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{

    Intent mIntent = new Intent(display_publishermagazine.this, display_publicationmagazine.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("position", position+1);
        startActivity(mIntent);
```

### act=2

```
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("position",0);

   switch (intValue)
    {
        case 1:values = new String[] { "Android For Beginer","Android Devloper" };break;
        case 2:values = new String[] { "I-phone for beginer","I-phone for devloper" };break;
        case 3:values = new String[] { "windows for beginer","windows for devloper" };break;
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

lisdis.setAdapter(adapter); 
    lisdis.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(display_publishermagazine.this, display_publicationmagazine.class);


    myIntent.putExtra("position", position+1);
    startActivity(myIntent);
   }
```

### act3

```
      Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
      int intValue = myIntent.getIntExtra("position", 0);

    switch (intValue)
    {
        case 1:values = new String[] { "Android for lerner1","android for learner2" };break;
        case 2:values = new String[] { "Android  for devloper1","android for devloper2" };break;
    }

/*values = new String[] { "iphone for lerner1","iphone for learner2" }      
values = new String[] { "iphone for devloper1","iphone for devloper2} */
}

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,

             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

        g1.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

I need to

- display data in another activity using switch case when user click on android
- then display data android Lerner or android developers.then  click on android learner
- then display android lerner1 or android learner2
- and when select android developer then display android lerner1 or android learner2.

Here it works for only android not work for iphone or window.

Comment: above code when i select any then display only android lerner or android devloper plz write a proper code.

Comment: edit and format you post properly.

Comment: thanks for reply..sir i want display a data from one activity to another activity in listview.in first activity data show android for beginner,android for learner.when user select android beginner then display data like.android for learner1 or android for lerner2.same for iphone  or window both.here i can manage only one android so how is posssible plz write code

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Link](http://www.listviewinandroid.blogspot.in/) which shows the same thing which you want to achieve.

It will help you.

Thanks.